# Conflict between the the integral and differential forms of Maxwell's equations

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors, calculus

Recently I made a question, you can click in this [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/756823/why-the-divernce-of-this-magnetic-field-is-not-zero/756874?noredirect=1#comment1695331_756874). I am having issues with the divergence of the magetic field in the orbital cylindrical frame, in which the divergence of the magnetic field is non-zero, contradicting Maxwell's equations. I revised the calculation and have not found any error.

The magnetic field in the orbital cylindrical frame is obtained by ordinary rotation matrix $R(\Omega,i\omega+f)$ 3-1-3, where the first rotation is about the $K$-axis, the longitude of ascending node $\Omega$, the second around the new $X^\prime$-axis, the inclination $i$, and the final rotation around the $K^\prime$-axis, is the sum of the periapsos argument $\omega$ and the true anomaly $f$, so the total angle of this final rotation is $\omega+f$. The result I obtain for the geomagnetic field is

$$\vec{B}=\frac{B_0 R^3}{r^3}[−2\sin i \sin(\omega+f)\, \hat{r}+\sin i cos(\omega+f)\,\hat{f} + \cos i\, \hat{k}].$$

And the divergence in cyllidrical coordinates, using Wolfram Mathematica is

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{B}=\frac{3 B_0 R^3 \sin i \sin(\omega+f)}{r^4},$$

Which contradicts the statement that the divergence of a magnetic field is always zero. However if I integrate this divergent over a volume I obtain the Integral form of Maxwell's equations

$$\int \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{S}= \int \nabla \cdot \vec{B} dV$$

$$\int \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{S}= \int_0^r \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_{-z}^z \nabla \cdot \vec{B} rdrdfdz=0.$$
Thus the integral form of Maxwell's equations are satisfied.
My question is if it is possible to interpret these results as the following statement:

"For this particular problem, the divergence of the magnetic field is non-zero because in this frame, in a particular region of space there are more field lines leaving then entering, or vice versa depending on the value of $\omega+f$, not because there is a magnetic monopole. However inside an entire volume of space, all lines entering also leves this volume, thus satisfying the integral form of Maxwell's equations."

This also makes me ask if the integral forms are more general than the differential forms. Can anyone answer both questions?

Comment: If the total field entering an elementary region is smaller than leaving it, (or vice-versa) there is a source in this region. And that would be a magnetic monopole.

Comment: Note that the integral form of Maxwells eqs. requires that the integral of the divergence of B vanishes for *any* integration region. You have only shown that it vanished for a *particular* volume defined by the ranges of integration. That does not prove that your field satisfies the integral form of Maxwell equations.

Comment: @JakobKS, so what should I do?

Comment: I’m assuming $\hat r$ is the same unit vector for spherical coordinates. You don’t define $\hat f,\hat k$ though. Also, are you assuming $\Omega,i,\omega+f$ to be position dependent or constant? These questions will determine what is the correct calculation of the divergence, which will be $0$ away from the origin.

Comment: @lpz, $\hat{r}$ is the same as cylindrical coordinates, $\hat{f}$ is analogous to $\phi$ in cylindrical coordinates and $\hat{k}$ is also the same.

Comment: $\Omega$, $i$ and $\omega$ are constant angles of a 3-1-3 rotation. Since my problem involves electrodynamics and orbital dynamics, one of the tasks is to convert the geomagnetic field from Cartesian coordinates to the orbital coordinates, which is given by a rotation matrix $R(\Omega,I,\omega+f)$

Comment: What do you mean by analogous? Is the vector $\hat f$ obtained from $\hat \phi$ by applying your three rotations? For $\hat k$, using your previous notation, do you mean that $\hat k=\hat K$?